# PHP Regex, remove string from another one if expression is valid

Tags: php, regex, php-7

There are many questions like this question but I can not find exact answer. And I am unfamiliar Regular Expresion topic.

PHP7 : I want to check if $str contains a html code and its `href` refer to the url : `"website.fr"` like `'<a href="www.website.fr/123/">*****</a>'`

i used the pattern  `<\b[a>]\S*\<\/a>` but is not working.
Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

This regexp catches an `a` element with an `href` attribute which refers to a `website.fr` url:

```
<a.*\shref="([^"]*\.)?website\.fr([.\/][^"]*)?"
```

Explanation:

- **`<a[^>]*`**: an anchor beginning
- **`\shref="`**: ...followed by an opened href attribute
- **`([^"]*\.)?`** : the URL may begin by anything except a quote and finishing by a dot
- **`website\.fr`** : your website
- **`([.\/][^"]*)?`**: the URL may finish by a slash followed by anything  except a quote

This regexp may not cover all cases (for example an URL containing a quote). Generally, it's discouraged to parse HTML with regexes. Better use a XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

In general, parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). In PHP, you can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search for elements with specific attributes in an HTML document. Something like this, which searches for an `<a>` element somewhere in the HTML which has an `href` value containing the string `'website.fr/'`:

```
$html = '<a href="www.website.fr/123/">*****</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
if (count($xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, 'website.fr/')]")))
    echo "found"; 
else
    echo "not found";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TP4RH)